# What is the best way for connecting 2 monitors to 2 laptops?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, displayport, kvm-switch, daisychaining

I have 2 laptops and I want to buy 2 monitors. So that I can share those 2 monitors between 2 laptops. I tried to find different possible solutions to achieve the same. As of now I can see 2 possible solutions.

1. KVM switch [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOtCt.png): As we can see in the diagram, this setup involves multiple wires. That's why I tried to find another solution.
2. Daisy chain with Displayport Switch [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcLHX.png): With this setup I can easily achieve what I want. But it looks like most of the monitors has displayport 1.2 whereas diplayport switch box has DP 1.4.

So the questions are,

- Is there displayport switch with DP 1.2 available in the market?
- Is there any other way to connect 2 monitors with 2 laptops?

Answer (score 0):

All DisplayPort versions are Backward Compatible with older versions.

This means that a DisplayPort 1.4 switch is expected to work with
DisplayPort 1.2 monitors and/or cables.

Comment: I'd rewrite that "will" as "is expected to". We do not live in a perfect world.

Comment: @Hannu: Yes, in a perfect world this site wouldn't be needed...